# Process GC-MS data in batch

Tags: python, batch-processing, chemistry

Here is my question.

- My lab has a GC-MS(Gas Chromatography-Mass Spectrometer) equipment which detect the concentration of volatile organic coumpounds(VOCs) per hour.
- So, as the time  accumulated, I have so many hourly data(.qgd format.) which all contain nearly 100 species' *Area*, *Height*, *Conc*, *Ret.time*,etc with the pre-builded method.
- My target now was to clip the concentration of each species for each files(one year = 8760 files). And it's quite a heavy job.

Does someone has a familiar experience with vast amount of experiment data which can only be opened by specific software?

Are there some kinds of method to deal wiht these file in batch?

PS: I'm familiar with Python language. If it can be achieved by Python, that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the features overview, [OPENChrom](http://openchrom.net) does support the import of files in the proprietary QGD format by Shimadzu.

If that doesn't work directly, you might try using the vendor software to export the original data to some (more) documented file formats, such as JCAMP-DX, netCDF or mzML first